# Find file that generated error CSRF TOKEN

Tags: laravel, csrf, laravel-5.6

I set up the `handler` file for whenever there is an error on the server, I receive an email with the details.

So today I received an email with the following error:

> array (3) {["message"] => string (0) "" ["file"] => string (104)
>   "/var/www/infochat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php"
>   ["line"] => int (71)}

I know what this error is, but the problem is that I do not know what caused it, what file or code it was responsible for.

I did not find anything in the logs (I may have seen the wrong log). Is there somewhere I can check to find out?

Comment: You might want to change how it was sent, maybe adding the path of the url. Without that, you need to check all modules that are using `VerifyCsrfToken`.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no way to tell which file sent it if that's the only thing youre getting from the error stack on your email.

I'd get a cup of coffee, fire up the IDE and start doing a "Find all" for "